# How to dynamically increase the length of the url?

Tags: asp.net, url, browser

How to dynamically increase the length of the url ?

Let me be more descriptive. I want to use it in asp.net version 2.0 and 3.5. The maximum length of the url in (IE 7 +) is 2048.

[Various size support in different browsers](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html):

IE 7 + - 2048
Firefox - 65000
Safari - 80000
Opera - 190000

Comment: Why do you want such a long URL?

Answer (score 1):

Put a query string on the url, and increase the size of it's value:

```
Response.Redirect("ThisPage.aspx?param=" + Request.QueryString("param") + "x");
```

Answer (score 1):

You add more characters to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.hugeurl.com/ ?

Seriously though, nothing stopping you from adding random junk to the query string.  If you want the URL to be immutable, include a checksum or something and require it to match the added text for the URL to resolve.  Or just use a reversible transformation to generate your URL, which is probably what hugeurl does.